# O menor valor de uma lista composta do Python está me retornando 0

Tags: python

Estou analisando os dados de uma lista. Onde tenho que mostrar as pessoas cadastradas e o peso delas.

```
def function(foo):
    print(foo)

pessoas = list()
dados = list()
maiorpeso = menorpeso = pessoasC = 0
while True:
    dados.append(str(input('Nome: ')))
    dados.append(float(input('Peso: ')))
    pessoas.append(dados[:])
    dados.clear()
    pessoasC += 1
    resp = str(input('Quer continuar? [S/N]')).strip().upper()[0]
    if resp in 'N':
        break
for p in pessoas:
    if p[1] == 0:
        maiorpeso = menorpeso = p[1]
    else:
        if p[1] > maiorpeso:
            maiorpeso = p[1]
        if p[1] < menorpeso:
            menorpeso = p[1]
print(f'O maior peso é {maiorpeso}')
print(f'O menor peso é {menorpeso}')
print(f'Ao todo você cadastrou {pessoasC} pessoas.')
```

Eu tenho que informar qual o menor peso desses dados e o maior.
fiz o contador de maior e menor e especifiquei que o primeiro pese seria o menor e o maior.
caso não for pedi para analisar que se os próximos da lista composta que vierem vai ser caso seja maior ou menor que já especifiquei.

Que ficou assim:

```py
for p in pessoas:
    if p[1] == 0:
        maiorpeso = menorpeso = p[1]
    else:
        if p[1] > maiorpeso:
            maiorpeso = p[1]
        if p[1] < menorpeso:
            menorpeso = p[1]
```

**Quando porém no final só me retorna o MAIOR PESO corretamente,
quando retorna o MENOR PESO entre os dados das listas compostas, me retorna "0"**

**Ficando assim:**

```py
Nome: Rodrigo
Peso: 72
Quer continuar? [S/N]s
Nome: Elon Musk
Peso: 50
Quer continuar? [S/N]n
O maior peso é 72.0
O menor peso é 0
Ao todo você cadastrou 2 pessoas.
```

Já tentei mudar as ordem das listas, deixar elas separadas, mas ainda me retorna o valor 0

Não posso usar determinando que o menor peso seja 999 para me basear nesse valor.

Comment: Não sei quais as restrições do exercício (o que pode ou não usar, se tem que fazer de determinado jeito, etc), mas segue algumas sugestões: https://ideone.com/A8t9bT - Se bem que daria para já ir verificando o maior e menor no mesmo loop que lê os dados: https://ideone.com/QsiWb2

Comment: Consegui resolver com Enumerate. Muito obrigado meu Nobre @hkotsubo

Answer (score -2):

O problema está na sua comparação. Você está usando a seguinte lógica:

```
    if p[1] < menorpeso:
        menorpeso = p[1]
```

Neste momento o `menorpeso` foi iniciado valendo 0, logo, nenhum peso que você inserir vai ser menor do que o valor atual e disparar o `if`.

Assim, altere a inicialização das variáveis:

```
maiorpeso, pessoasC = 0, 0
menorpeso = 999
```

Não entendi porque você está fazendo a seguinte lógica para printar:

```
print(f'O menor peso é {min(pessoas[1])}')
```

Eu trocaria para:

```
print(f'O menor peso é {menorpeso}')
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava editando e acabei mudando a linha para:

```py
print(f'O menor peso é {min(pessoas[1])}')
```

*já foi alterado para {menorpeso}. Que era o que estava dando erro*

**Sobre a sua sugestão:**

Na aula que estou tendo, não pode usar esse menor = 999, editei a pergunta colocando essa regra. Obrigado

La em cima eu determinei que a primeira posição do laço já é o menor e o maior peso.
(Porque ele vai ser o primeiro peso a ser acrescentado, ou seja ele no momento é o maior e o menor).

Senão:
Se:
os próximos números acrescentados forem menores ou maiores, o número que foi acrescentado vai receber a variável de maior ou menor peso.

A condição está dando certo para o maior peso. Porém para o menor peso está dando 0, mesmo eu colocando outros dados. Ou deixando só meu dado que já seria o menor e maior porque é único.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Vc não está vendo se a primeira posição é zero, e sim se o primeiro elemento é.

Comment: Vou verificar sua sugestão lá em cima, muito obrigado!